# Implementing Subclassing in the Database

Tags: oop, database-design

I'm developing an application that will have a parent class which will have many basic fields and methods,  and several subclasses with additional fields methods.

Curious how best to implement in the database. Does it make sense to have one table for the parent class, a separate table for the subclass and link them via id fields, or is it better to duplicate the parent class fields in the subclass tables for ease of access and simpler querying?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes, those are both valid approaches. It depends on things like how many joins you want done when you query something, and whether you want polymorphic queries to be supported. [Here's an article on the subject by Scott Ambler.](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html#MappingInheritance) Section 2.6 in the article has a nice table that lists advantages and disadvantages of different mapping approaches.

Comment: Thanks for that article. That and a fair amount of googling has taught me a lot. I'm still in the very early stages of designing this app, so it's not set in stone yet, but I'm leaning toward one table per class. I don't want one big table, because some subtypes have lots of extra attributes, and a table that sparse (for other types) seems suboptimal. I hope by creating the right views, I can enjoy the benefits of separate tables and still have some fair ease of use in getting at the data. But as I said, it's early days yet, so this may change. Thanks to ALL for giving me a lot ot hink about!!

Comment: This article was very helpful (y)

Answer (score 6):

Three usual ways

1. Table per hierarchy -- one table for everything, lots of NULL columns.
2. Table per concrete class; each sub-class gets a table with all common fields repeated.
3. Table per type (class). This is as in **[supertype/subtype approach](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user:196713%20subtype)** in relational design.

Answer (score 0):

you're basically talking about the object relational impedence mismtach. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch

The simplest answer is that you model you data differently when it is in a relational database than when it is in object form.